# Problem to identify the window handle and window name of a UIelement

Tags: c, com, ui-automation

Objective: I am using the library Uiautomation.h to retrieve the window handle (hwnd) and window name when the user clicks on one element of that window. I need a solution with plain C.

Example: If the User clicks on the button 8 of the windows calculator, I need to identify the window handle and name as follow:

[image]

I am retrieving no window when the user clicks into a element of the windows calculator:
hwnd = 0
Window name = none

I am retrieving always 0 as hwnd. However, when I click in the header of the window, I can retrieve the hwnd and the window name as "Calculator". This is part of my code in plain C:

```
UIA_HWND hwnd;
PWSTR win_name = NULL;
static int win_len;
POINT pt;
IUIAutomation *pAutomation = NULL;
IUIAutomationElement *element = NULL;

CoInitialize(NULL);
EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_CUIAutomation;
EXTERN_C const IID IID_IUIAutomation;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_CUIAutomation,NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,&IID_IUIAutomation,(void**)&pAutomation);

GetCursorPos(&pt);
hr = IUIAutomation_ElementFromPoint(pAutomation, pt, &element);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && element != NULL){
  IUIAutomationElement_get_CurrentNativeWindowHandle(element,&hwnd);
  win_len = GetWindowTextLengthW(hwnd);
  if(win_len > 0) {     
      win_name = (PWSTR) malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * win_len + 1);
      GetWindowTextW(hwnd, win_name, win_len + 1);
  }
}
```

I used also the function `hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();` but I still get the same value 0. Could someone know what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Why do you try to use the HWND directly? you should continue with UI automation, traverse its hierarchy, get to the element you need, its properties, etc. Use "inspect" tool from the Windows SDK to first discover all that and then code it.

Comment: @SimonMourier tks for your help. If I understood you well I should find the ancestor of that element which is a window Control Type and the get the name property?. If so, Do you know how can I move throught back its top anscestor?

Comment: You can navigate the tree using IUIAutomationTreeWalker (ex: IUIAutomationTreeWalker_GetParentElement)